# ORA-20000: APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER Cannot Be Rest Enabled from Rest Administration Interface

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle18c

Using Oracle 18c xe and ords 19.1 when enabling Rest Administration interface I am getting error

> "ORA-20000: APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER Cannot Be Rest Enabled from Rest Administration Interface"

Do i need to provide any user with admin privileges for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the reason is that APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER is created as an "Oracle Maintained" user when APEX is installed. However, one of the recent changes in ORDS is that these "Oracle Maintained" schemas cannot be REST-Enabled any more.

In general, I would not spend too much time on the "REST Administrative Interface" any more. This will be deprecated in the upcoming APEX release 20.1 and desupported in a future release. On the other hand, ORDS will support a similar interface in one of the next versions. Basically, as soon as the interface is available in ORDS, it will be removed from APEX.

If you want to use the interface *right now*, you can use the following workaround:

```
--
-- drop the Oracle Maintained user APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER
--
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

drop user APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER;

alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=false;

--
-- recreate APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER as a non Oracle Maintained user
--

create user apex_instance_admin_user no authentication;

grant create session to APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER;
```

After that, enabling the REST Admin Interface should work.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue and tracked as bug number 30426865. Is APEX installed into the CDB or into the PDB in your installation?

Comment: APEX is installed in PDB , bug number 30426865 is inaccessible to me. Is there any other article from where it can be fixed